# How duplicate file input after selecting a file ( .change() )

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Trying to create an input field for file uploads .. I want when the user selects a file , the file input field gets duplicated with a new empty one

what I used was something like this

```
<form>
<input type='file' class='addImage' />
</form>


$(function(){ 
        $('.addImage').change(function(){
            $("<input type='file' class='addImage' />").appendTo('form');
        });
    });
```

See it live here http://jsfiddle.net/R5QSy/1/

It works and display only another single file input duplicate .. if I select a file from the new generated input, no more duplication occurs ! how can I make the duplication process unlimited ? thanks

Comment: use event delegation for elements that don't exists when code runs. When you replace an element, it's event binding is lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second file input that gets added does not yet exist at the time your function attaches the `change` handler, so it does not respond to the `change` event. You can fix this by using a delegated event handler instead:

```
$(document).on("change", ".addImage", function(){ ... });
```

Note that this will probably not be satisfactory as it stands, since every time you change the selected file on any of the elements a new file input will be added (even if there are already unused input controls in the form). You can prevent this from happening by adding a class to any element when the handler is invoked on it and checking that it does not already have the class before adding a new element.

Comment: As an alternative to the class solution, you could change the selector to `.addImage:last`.